# error while using cancan in ruby: "uninitialized constant CanCan::Rule::Mongoid"

Tags: ruby, authorization, cancan

here is my controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user
  authorize_resource :class => false

  def index
  end

  def users_list
  end

end
```

here is my Ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

when trying to access "/admin/users_list" (with an admin user or without) i get the following error:

> uninitialized constant CanCan::Rule::Mongoid

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just recently, CanCan [added support for Mongoid](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/commit/a6959c0ab2218508ec38a19744eb0fc9c75a0000) and [renamed `CanDefinition` to `Rule`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/commit/37c149182c5566c0928e8d4d0f6e767951e59c9b), so the error you are getting indicates you are using the latest CanCan code from the git repo.

Try out CanCan version 1.4 from rubygems and see if that solves the problem. There may be some bug fixes needed before 1.5 is released to rubygems.

UPDATE:

This bug was fixed in CanCan version 1.5.0.beta1.

Comment: my current CanCan plugin version is 1.4.1, is this the version i need to use? how do i avoid the bug in this version?

Comment: Version 1.4.1 FROM THE GITHUB REPO has the bug. Version 1.4.1 from http://rubygems.org/ does NOT have the bug. How are you installing CanCan? As a plugin or a gem? The easiest solution is to install as a Gem from rubygems. Or, you can use my fork of CanCan at https://github.com/bowsersenior/cancan for now until the fix is merged into the main CanCan repository.

Comment: This fix has been pulled in, thanks bowsersenior. I also changed the version in the GitHub repository to 1.5.0.beta1 to avoid confusion.